# Birthday Problem

Tags: probability, birthday

What is the approximate probability (in percentage) that at least $2$ people in a group of $6$ randomly-selected have a birthday on the same day of the week?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: The general problem even has the same name. Plugging it into google will give you a lot of helpful references wich you can use to at least do _something_ of your own and show your work.

Answer (score -1):

$1-\frac{365*(365-7)*(365-14)*(362-21)*(361-28)*(360-35)}{365^6}$

Comment: Why do you subtract multiples of $7$?

Comment: Because in the second term I am calculating the probability of no two people sharing the same birthday week. Hence $-7$.

Comment: There are roughly $52$ weeks in a year: $52$ mondays, $52$ tuesdays... Here no two people must share the same *day of week*.

Comment: Ok, I interpreted the problem improperly. I thought they shouldn't share the same birthday week.